# Can I pass a type as an argument to a generic when the type is an extension of enums?

Tags: typescript, generics

If I have two `enums`:

```
export enum First {
   One = "One"
}
```

```
export enum Second {
   Two = "Two"
}
```

And I combine them into a type:

```
export type Combined = One | Two;
```

Is it ok to pass `Combined` like so:

```
export type FooType = Record<Combined, unknown>;
```

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about?  What's the use case?  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

No reason it wouldn't work !

```
export enum First {
   One = "One"
}
export enum Second {
   Two = "Two"
}
export type Combined = First.One | Second.Two;

export type FooType = Record<Combined, unknown>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsoGd4DeAsAFBzkDyiwcAvHAERXAOkC%20poksCK6AysADGERABM4xMuQAqAdwh1G8iKxIcSXaPBgBPMDQDCEVACMs1CfWx4YAOmZwAPnEEjxdlQG5SncNrg9A0wICBl9GnoAJWFoMQAeYzMLYDEAGjhkRABrRAg5RAA%20LyA)

Comment: Thanks it was more a sense check on my part.